# How to replace string in "%" in make file

Tags: docker, makefile

I have follow folder with Dockerfile

- build

  - path1

    - v1

      - Dockerfile
    - v2

      - Dockerfile
  - path2

    - v1

      - Dockerfile

I collect it as $(DOCKER_TARGES) --->  build-path1-v1 build-path1-v2 build-path2-v2

Now my target

```
build-%: build/$(subst -,/,%))/Dockerfile $(shell find build -type f)
```

I try to replace string in `%` but it could not work. any suggestion?

Comment: HardcoreHenry has a good solution.  But I wonder, is there any reason you can't just name your targets `build-path1/v1` and `build-path2/v2` etc.?  There's no rule against make variables containing `/` in their names, or almost any other special character for that matter.  If you did that you might not need to play tricks with converting filenames.

Comment: Also, is `$(shell build -type f)` really right?  If it is, that doesn't depend on anything related to a specific target and I urge you to assign it into a separate variable with `:=` so it's only invoked one time: `BUILD_FILES := $(shell find build -type f)` then use that variable as the prerequisite.  But probably, you meant do have it only depend on the files in a particular subdirectory and this is wrong (will rebuild everything if anything changes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with [secondary expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html):

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
build-%: build/$$(subst -,/,%) $$(shell find build -type f)
```

Note the double `$$` signs - as these will expand to dollar signs in the final expansion.   You can also do this with a define, though I hate doing this because it can cause unseen bloat:

```
define MKRULE 
   build-$1: build/$$(subst -,/,$1) $$(shell find build -type f)
endef

foreach(f,$(TARGS),$(eval $(call MKRULE $f)))
```